# Codeigenator bonfire fetch_row is not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, bonfire

**Check below code :**

```
$data["results"] = $this->useer_model->mysqli_fetch_row($config["per_page"], $page);
$str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
$data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to get data

```
$data['result']=$this->db->get('Table', limit, offset)->result();
foreach($data['result'] as $value){
 echo $value->coloum_nam;
```